# webpage with home and about us link with edit button using ember js

Tags: ember.js

Simply I want single application page, in that there should be two navigation menus Home and About Us by clicking on that the related content should open in same page as well as there should be edit button where i can edit contents and Menu's link using Ember Js. Please Help.

Comment: What's your question??

Comment: The question is definitely missing. Try to spend more time explaining the issue and detailing the question you are trying to find the answer to.

Comment: Simply I want single application page, in that there should be two navigation menus Home and About Us by clicking on that the related content should open in same page as well as there should be edit button where i can edit contents and Menu's link using Ember Js. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

this is not much of a question
but to answer the somewhat ambiguous question that you are perhaps asking where you could start,

try these starting as a starting point

the [Ember Guide's Getting Started](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/)

This [Tutsplus' dive into Ember](https://tutsplus.com/course/lets-learn-ember/)

or this [In-depth-guide on smashing](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/)

I found it easier to start with a static page without a server